# searching for the right coordinate for drawing a line with an angle

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to shade a polygon with lines which are drawn in a specific angle. 
I already have found all points with a scanline algorithm of the polygon in an ArrayList of ArrayList of Points.
This means in the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>` are `ArrayList<Point>` which have all Points for a Polygon with one y value. For example these 2 Points for a rectangle `(2,2)` and `(5,2)`. So the outer ArrayList contains all the horizontal points which can be drawn with `drawLine()`.
Now I have to calculate the end points x2 and y2 for `drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)`.

Is there any possibility to get the right points of the polygon for x2 and y2?

Comment: So you're trying to find the intersection of your line with the side of the polygon?

Comment: yes, thats what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to achieve this manually is rather difficult.

Consider setting the clip path in Graphics2D using your polygon as a Shape. Then, from points on the base line of the bounding rectangle of your polygon, draw the shading lines long enough to exceed the parallel line of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can look on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) for how to find line-line intersections.

The only difficulty is making sure that the intersection is actually on the right side of the line segment. One option is just to check that the coordinates of the intersection are in the boundary of the rectangle formed by the two endpoints of the polygon side. You can easily do this by just comparing the coordinates.

Once you have found the intersection for that line on both sides of the polygon, you can then use `g.drawLine()` to connect them.

The naive, and simple solution to finding the two sides of the polygon (as long as it's convex), is to loop over all of the sides until you find two that have the intersection in the bounds of the side. Then, just connect those two intersections.